# Best Way to Deny Packages from Foreign Architecture?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

#### Question

What is the best way to block installation of packages from a foreign architecture on Ubuntu or Debian, or even better prevent adding that foreign architecture in the first place?

#### Context

I maintain Docker images containing entire toolchains for cross-compilation, so people can cross-compile code with minimal setup. These images are based off of Ubuntu (or Debian) so users can install any C or C++ dependencies to cross-compile their code. However, for some targets, such `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`, which is a hard-float, ARMv6 target (this is the Rust target triple), the foreign architecture seems compatible but is not. The `armhf` foreign architecture is compiled for ARMv7-A, and therefore is not compatible with ARMv6 platforms, but most users do not know this.

This is particularly bad, since any code built and linked against these system libraries will compile and link without warning, but will fail to run on native hardware. Unless users are actively testing their code using Qemu for a specific CPU or on native hardware as part of their pipeline, they will detect this at the worst time.

Since we can't move off of our Debian or Ubuntu image bases without breaking changes, and users still need to install architecture-agnostic utilities such as Ninja or the Meson build system, we can't simply say that using the system package manager is off-limits for all images.

What we're currently considering is using a wildcard with package pinning to prevent an installation target from being found for all `armhf`-architecture packages (saved to `/etc/apt/preferences.d/all-packages`):

```
Package: *:armhf
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

I believe this is the best solution, since I have found no way to prevent adding the foreign architecture itself to the sources. I believe there is no way to prevent `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`, and so blocking those packages via package pinning is the best solution.

Is there a better way? We're deploying these images to large numbers of users, and these images are used in numerous CI pipelines: we'd rather not having something unintended break or have a less-than-comprehensive solution.

#### Footnotes

† And yes, this can be undone, since merely removing this file and re-updating the sources will remove any blocked packages via pinning. This should require someone who is actively trying to install incompatible packages, or basically require someone with some experience who can understand the consequences of their actions.